# Coulomb repulsion in the Anderson impurity model

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, strong-correlated

In Phil Anderson's famous paper on impurities, *[Localized Magnetic States in Metals](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.124.41)*, he has the following paragraph on page 44,

[image]

However, I am puzzled by the last sentence: why is the $J$ part really only a one-electron energy $n_{\uparrow} + n_{\downarrow}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because 
$$
n_\downarrow n_\downarrow = n_\downarrow
$$
and similarly for $n_\uparrow$.

Why? Because $n_\downarrow$ can only take on the values 0 or 1 and 
$$
0^2=0
$$
and
$$
1^2=1
$$

Comment: I should have known that. One more question is that he seems to make a distinction between the terms "exchange" and "correlation", but sometimes not. Any indication?

Comment: Not sure of his motivation for doing that. They are not  the same thing.

Comment: Yes. The two terms he uses also differ from those used by others. Why is $U$ the exchange self-energy?

Comment: "Exchange" is called "exchange" because it looks like it results from "exchanging" labels in the two-electron operator for the interaction. I believe that this is explained well in one of my favorite books: "Intermediate Quantum Mechanics" by Hans Bethe.

Comment: Not good. It does not answer my question. $U$, to me, is just a Coulomb integral.

Comment: I suggest you pose this as a separate question on Physics Stack Exchange.